# What is a NPR Syntax?

Tags: database

what is a NPR syntax, from what i have gathered from internet, i have come to conclusion that  NPR is a  performance related database. Its based on [NPR database](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v8r1/topic/com.ibm.netcool_pm.doc/TQLwithNPR.pdf)

Given that what i have gathered is correct, how do i extract data from this Database, what language\Tools should i be using?

Comment: It is kind of like using [butterflies to program](http://xkcd.com/378/), but instead you talk in a soft and consistent tone about world news or other cultural topics.

Comment: Did you read the link?  They specifically define (in depth) TSQL queries.  What didn't you like about the language/tools in the link you provided?

Comment: @Lott, i did go through the pdf entirely, what i was not sure is,  if tomorrow i get this NPR file\database, how do i open it and what tool do i use to connect to and run queries on it.Please note that it is part of the client requirement and i do not have files in hand. i was just prepping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.npr can be a number of things (among others a lotus-notes file and an audio-file). From your question i gather you are not really sure it really is the database-related file-format from IBM?

Have you tried reading its magic number ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29))? Just open it in wordpad (if you are on windows) and tell us the first 200 characters of the file so we can be sure of which it is.

I will then adapt this answer of course.

Comment: eznme, it's a part of requirement given by our client, which says we have to extract data using NPR syntax. and i am sure it will not  be lotus notes or Audio related file. I do not have sample file with me yet. I will definitely update this post when i have one.